# How to access nested attributes from an API using Angular

Tags: angular, api, nested, frontend

I'm using Angular to get data from an API. I had been following [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yAT2HHusDDk) youtube video but accessing nested attributes is not demonstrated.

How would you access the "address" attributes like "street" and "city" from https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Seeing your **API**, your data structure has **nested objects**, whereas the tutorial you refer only gives example of a **plain object**.

The above answers also suggest right way to access nested properties in an object, but in this case I would suggest you build your object in a right way so that angular automatically map your nested objects correctly.

Something like this.

```
export class Location{
    public lat: string;
    public lng: string;
}
  export class Company{
      public name: string;
      public catchPhrase: string;
      public bs: string;
  }
  
  export class Address{
    public street: string;
    public suite: string;
    public city: string;
    public zipcode: string;
    public geo: Location;
}
export class User{
    public id: number;
    public name: string;
    public username: string;
    public email: string;
    public address: Address;
    public phone: string;
    public website: string;
    public company: Company;
}
```

This way when you call the http get service you get your records in the correct nested format that you can access later on. For example

```
this._http.get<User[]>(this.apiUrl);
```

Now you can use the dot operator (.) to access nested objects inside the User object.

Answer (score 1):

Well lets say you want to access the first object of the array. And the API response is placed in a response variable:

```
const response = data //the data received from the API
const address = response[0].address;
const street = address.street;
const city = address.city
```

Comment: Thanks a ton! Doesn't this download all the data though. Is there a way to use a class to get just a few attributes?

Comment: If your api returns all the data then you cant do anything, If you want less data you have to change the API

Answer (score 0):

You can access them with below code. Say `propertiesList` as response json then

```
...
 const addressList = this.propertiesList.map(prop -> prop.address ? 
                      { 'street' : prop.address.street, 'city' : prop.address.city } : null );
...
```

you can access them with help of index

```
const street = addressList[0].street;
const city = addressList[0].city;
```